# RegEx for matching alternating case letters

Tags: regex

I would like to detect the following sequences:

```
a
aA
aAa
aAaA
...
```

where a~[a-z] and A~[A-Z], the case alternates and the first letter is always lower-case.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex that @tanascius gave is fine, and based on that, a shorter one could be:

```
([a-z][A-Z])*[a-z]?
```

A major difference is that this one will match the empty string.  I wasn't sure from the examples if that was allowed.

Comment: +1 too: If a zero-length string is valid, this would be the way to go.  But I think @tanascius is right, and at least one character is required.

Answer (score 17):

```
[a-z]([A-Z][a-z])*[A-Z]?
```